# How can I obtain monthly unemployment by ethnicity by state for the US?

Tags: labor-economics, data-request, unemployment, paneldata, united-states

Grateful for any help, thoughts and direction.

Comment: Do you need the data specifically by state?

Comment: Yes, I need data by state. I already have national unemployment by ethnicity data on a monthly basis.